# How are shiny odds affected by breeding shiny parents in Pokemon GSC?

Tags: pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

I have heard that if you use shiny parents in Pokémon GSC, the likelihood of hatching a shiny Pokémon will be increased.

Is this true? and if so, what are the odds?

Comment: Related: [Were shiny Ditto more likely to produce shiny offspring?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/109648/were-shiny-ditto-more-likely-to-produce-shiny-offspring?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, shiny parents are more likely to produce shiny offspring in generatation 2. The chance is 1/64 in any of the following cases:

- Both parents are shiny
- One parent is a shiny Ditto
- One parent is shiny, the other is not Ditto, and the child is the opposite sex of the shiny parent

[This is due to the way stats are passed down.](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_breeding#Generation_II) IVs, which are responsible for shininess, are partially inherited from the Ditto parent if a Ditto is involved, or from the opposite parent if not, i.e. a male baby will inherit based on its mother's IVs.

Since a shiny pokemon has, by definition, the correct IVs to be shiny, inheriting those stats increases the chance of being shiny.

The maths itself, and the 1/64 chance, can be found in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/109656/53291).